# curl login to website returned blank screen

Tags: php, curl

No error, it just show a blank screen, I have no idea where has gone wrong in myt case.

```
$username = 'myname';
$password = 'mypass';
$loginUrl = 'https://example.com/login/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content;
```

Comment: I think you have to disclose URL of the login page. Otherwise we only can guess about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

add this option in case of url with HTTPS and see if you can get some information:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Now, try:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for curl errors.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```

If curl_exec returns false. Echo of the contents returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some errors but if error reporting is disabled on the server side you might not just see it.

You can check the returning http headers, they might give you some ideas.